# Print array of imagefield fields for node type

Tags: 6, media

I need to get an array of imagefields for a specific node type or even just all imagefields or all fields for a node type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all fields for a particular content type using the [`content_types()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21cck%21content.module/function/content_types/6) function:

```
$type = content_types($type_name);

if (isset($type['fields'])) {
  $fields = $type['fields'];
}
```

From there you can just loop through and see what type of field each is, and act on it accordingly.

Comment: This is helpful but imagefields are specified as filefields, is there a way to differentiate between the two?

Comment: There might be a better way but you could look at the `widget` for each field; if it's an `imagefield_widget` you can be pretty certain it's an image field type